# ld: cannot find -lmpif (even though library is linked)

Tags: fortran, mpi, ld

I know a lot of people have asked similar questions but I cannot find an answer that works for me. I am trying to compile and eventually run a program called zeus-mp which relies on the mpi library. I am simply following the instructions provided with the code and have edited the make file to reflect the system on which I am trying to run it. When I run `make all` I get the following ouput.

```
ifort  -O2 -msse2 -I/usr/include/mpi -I/hpcwarwick/ompi/1.4.5/intel/12.1/include -o ../exe/zeusmp.x advx1.o    advx2.o advx3.o avisc.o avisc_d.o bndyflgs.o bval3d.o bvalemf.o clocks.o  ct.o dataio.o diverg.o empty.o findno.o forces.o forces_d.o fourn.o  ggen.o grdv.o hdfall.o hsmoc.o intchk.o lorentz.o lorentz_d.o maxmin.o  mnmx.o momx1.o momx2.o momx3.o movie.o msave2.o mget2.o mstart.o newdt.o  newgrid.o newvg.o newx1.o newx2.o nudt.o pdv.o pdv_d.o pressure.o printd.o restart.o setup.o spenergy.o srcstep.o strtoi.o transprt.o  tranx1.o tranx2.o tranx3.o tslice.o zeusmp.o writeout.o textdmp.o   linpck.o debug.o rad_loss.o kin_visc.o tconduct.o modulo.o pnewt.o  nantest.o  box.o bcdflt.o checkin.o mmIsFinite.o mmIsNan.o -L/usr/lib64 - L/usr/lib/mpi/lib -L/hpcwarwick/ompi/1.4.5/intel/12.1/lib - L/storage/home/maths/marxzq/HDF4/hdf4lib/lib -ldl -lnsl -lutil -lmfhdf - ldf -lmpi -lmpif -lpthread
ld: cannot find -lmpif
make: *** [../exe/zeusmp.x] Error 1
```

The file mpif.h is in the directory /hpcwarwick/ompi/1.4.5/intel/12.1/include which I believe I have linked correctly. I have even tried moving mpif.h into the directory in which make is ran but that failed with the same error as well. If anyone could help I would be really grateful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't confuse compilation with linking. You are telling the linker to find and link a *library* called libmpif. Does such a library exist?

Comment: The loader (or compiler if you're not quite sure what a loader is) is complaining that it can't find a library it calls `lmpif` but which, were you to find it in the file structure, would have a name like `libmpif.so`.  But you write about the existence of a header file called `mpif.h`.  The two are not the same - suggesting you don't understand the difference.  Please clarify.

Comment: So from my understanding `*.h` files are header files which link to the libraries found in `.../intel/12.1/lib` correct? This is where I thought the problem may be as there is not a `libmpif.so` but there is a `libmpi_f77.so` and a `libmpi_f90.so`. I (perhaps naively) thought that `mpif.h` would link to either of these since they are both fortran and there is not a `mpi_f77.h` or `mpi_f90.h`.  Please correct me if I am wrong there though, I am quite new to this.

Comment: `*.h` files have nothing to do with linking, *per se*. The don't control linking behaviour in any way. At this point I am not sure what it is you are trying to do or ask here, but I don't you are either. Can you edit your question to explain clearly what it is you are trying to do, and describe exactly what problem you encountered that led to you decide to try linking a .h file?

Comment: I have edited the question slightly but I don't really understand what you are wanting me to expand on. I am essentially trying to run `make all` and this is the error I get. The program relies on having the mpi library and `-I/path/to/include/directory` and `-l[library]` is how I have always included libraries in the past (admittedly I don't have a vast amount of experience)  and is indeed how it was done in the instructions provided with this code. All I have really done is change the paths to reflect the system I am attempting to run it on.

Comment: Yes but are you using the same compiler and MPI version as the instructions (wherever they are, you haven't said)? Are you even sure that your MPI flavour has and/or requires a library called libmpif.so? You probably need to read the instructions for whatever mpi version you are using (my guess is Intel's flavour of mpich2 but again you haven't said) and modify the makefile accordingly

Comment: I'd like to emphasize the comment of @talonmies about **requiring** the libraries. I've used several MPI implementations as a user, but I only ever needed to include `mpif.h` and have a corresponding `-I/.../include/...` part during building, no `-lmpi*` was needed. So are you sure you need it in the first place?

Comment: Ok I am using ifort which is supported by the code, and yes I did modify the Makefile for this. The MPI flavour I am using is open mpi 1.4.5. I believe the issue lies in the fact that the library `libmpif.so` does NOT exist. The only libraries that do exist are `libmpi.so`, `libmpi_f77.so` and `libmpi_f90.so`. However, the only header files are `mpi.h`, `mpif.h` and `mpi_common.h`. I am 99% sure the library is installed correctly since I did not install it myself but it was done by whoever manages my universities cluster. I was hoping someone could explain this quirk with open mpi.

Comment: But you still haven't answered the question - what possessed you to decide you need to link libmpif.so in the first place? Where did it come from? Was it in the original Makefile or instructions? Did you add it yourself? Do the instructions for OpenMPI say you must link that library? What happens if you just don't link it?

Comment: 1. Isn't there a wrapper at your cluster? Like calling `mpif90` instead of `ifort`, I usually see those at clusters. 2. As again @talonmies is spot-on: throw away the `libmpi*` `L/*mpi*` part and see what happens (you need to run it too, just a few nodes is enough to see if it works).

Comment: Yes it was in the original Makefile, I just edited the paths that were there so that they corresponded to my system. When using libraries with fortran you do need the `-l[library]` part, see here http://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/18.3_libraries.html. Throwing that part away causes lots of other errors about loads of MPI specific things not being defined.

Comment: There is an `mpifort` wrapper but using `ifort` was how it was done in the original Makefile so I have kept it at that and have only edited paths and system specific parts.

Comment: Then try `mpifort`, which is specific to your cluster (where you actually want to use your program). This could do exactly what you want: select the proper libraries. I assume the makefile came with the program, not with the cluster, so they don't assume anything about any wrappers present at your cluster. **EDIT**: I mean `mpifort` plus only include-type MPI stuff.

Comment: As I already said, the solution is to remove the MPI specific libraries from the original  Makefile you haven't shown us, and replace it with the correct libraries for your MPI version and installation.

Comment: @talonmies OP did replace the paths in the makefile, but it still doesn't work. The fact that there are `libmpi_f77.so` and `libmpi_f90.so` and not a unique one tells me that a wrapper is necessary, I guess just throwing in `-lmpif90` wouldn't work.

Comment: @AndrasDeak using the wrapper did work as you suggested, thank you for helping and answering what now seems to be a silly question, I am not a computer scientist by any means but have been thrown in at the deep end for my PhD so get overwhelmed sometimes! talonmies As repeatedly stated I had already edited the Makefile.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Paths and libraries aren't the same thing. I am guessing the makefile contains specific incantations for a different mpi flavour that need to be changed. That is the underlying source of the problem. As you have said, most modern MPI installations have wrappers which should make all this unecessary, but this makefile clearly doesn't use them.

Comment: @talonmies: sure, I just meant that it should not be that hard to locate your libraries, and I assumed that OP filled in the necessary blanks. (But obviously you have a perfect point with the invisibility of the makefile to us here at SO).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: You should add a short answer so this question can be put to bed.

Comment: @talonmies thanks, just did. @Nick: did you use the wrapper+`-libmpi`, or could you omit the MPI libraries? In the latter case I would add this to my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventual solution in comments copied to proper answer:

You need a wrapper specific to you cluster which will take care of the proper MPI libraries for you. These wrappers are often called `mpif77`, `mpif90` etc., at HPC Warwick it seems to be called `mpifort`.